# Prevent bottomTabs buttons and text animation when active in Android react-native-navigation v2

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm using `react-native-navigation v2 3.7.0` from Wix, and particularly in Android only, whenever you tap any button, it increases the fontSize by 2px (it's 12px), and pushes the icon up too, plus it adds an extra bubble effect that increases size with opacity animation.

I set the fontSize to be 10px in the tab setup, and it increases to 12px when active. If I set it to 12, it won't increase size, but I don't want it to be 12px, it's too big for me.

This is the example of my of my current stacks:

```
 stack: {
                            id: 'MessageTabStack',
                            children: [
                                {
                                    component: {
                                        id: 'MessageScreen',
                                        name: 'myApp.MessageScreen'
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            options: {
                                bottomTab: {
                                    fontSize: 10,
                                    text: i18n.t('messages'),
                                    icon: iconsMap['message-light'],
                                    selectedIcon: iconsMap['message-solid'],
                                    badgeColor: 'red',
                                    ...navigatorStyle
                                }
                            }
                        }
```

Is there any way to remove these animations in Android?